# Acumatica Override _(FieldVerifying<field> e)

Tags: overriding, acumatica

I need to override this event in ARInvoiceEntry.

```
protected virtual void _(Events.FieldVerifying<ARTran.curyRetainageAmt> e)
```

This is the code I have to override the above.

```
 public class ARInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
    public delegate void _Delegate(Events.FieldVerifying<ARTran.curyRetainageAmt> e);
    [PXOverride]
    public void _(Events.FieldVerifying<ARTran.curyRetainageAmt> e, _Delegate baseMethod)
    {
      baseMethod(e);
    }
    #endregion
  }
```

However the above is giving me an error:

`Invalid argument type in the event handler PX.Objects.AR.ARInvoiceEntry_Extension::_`

How would I override an "_" event method?

I have tried this, which then doesn't override the method.

```
  public class ARInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
    [PXOverride]
    public void _(Events.FieldVerifying<ARTran.curyRetainageAmt> e)
    {
     // do my stuff
    }
    #endregion
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With event handlers, you do not have to do pxoverride. You add a second method with the same signature, and then can call the basemethod parameter.

```
        public void _(Events.FieldVerifying<ARTran.curyRetainageAmt> e, PXFieldVerifying baseMethod)
        {
            baseMethod?.Invoke(e.Cache, e.Args);
        }
```

the ?.Invoke calls the base function only if it is set, so you do not need to check for nulls.